# Using a UIButton inside a UITextField as a clear button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

what i am trying to do is do a custom clear button in a UITextField, currently i have got everything working except for the last part. Which is getting it to preform the clear action. However, i have not been able to work out how i can get it to clear, just the textField it is in.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.56f green:0.56f blue:0.56f alpha:1.00f]];
    [textField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteCell"];

    UIButton *btnColor = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnColor addTarget:self action:@selector(clearText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnColor.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
    [btnColor setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearBut"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    textField.rightView = btnColor;
    textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [textField addSubview:btnColor];


    return YES;
}
```

This is how i've created the button in the textField, and for it to only show when editing, as you can see i have it calling `clearText` however i'm unsure how i can send the current textField name i am in to be cleared in the `clearText` call.

I know I can do it the hard way, and define it individually for each of my textFields, but i'm sure there is an easier way to go about this, that i just haven't realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest subclassing `UITextField`. This will not allow you to lay out the button in a Storyboard, but in Code or as a .nib file should work. Of course you can use the `UITextfield` subclass in a storyboard.

Inside the subclass add a `UIButton` as a subview and in its action method call:
`self.text = @""`

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your button has been added to the text field as a sub-view you can get to the text field in the buttons superview property:

```
- (void) clearText:(UIButton*)sender
{
    UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)sender.superview;
    textField.text = nil;
}
```